How to see incoming commits in IntelliJ IDEA similarly to VS Code
In VS Code, on Source Control view at left, you can see incoming changes grouped by commits. You can explore commits, see changed files, and examine individual changes.
In IntelliJ IDEA, there seems to be no easy way of doing that. Only when you update your branch with remote commits, you are presented with Update Info tab on Git view at the bottom, which shows information very much matching the one VS Code presents before you pull.
Is there a way of seeing what you are going to pull in IntelliJ similar to how VS Code presents it? And is there a way for VS Code to view what was updated after you pulled remote commits, similarly to Update Info tab in IntelliJ IDEA?

Instead of pulling, you could fetch a branch and then inspect the changes that the remote's branch would bring.

Select the tracking branch on the bottom left.

Select a desired commit in the commit list at the bottom.

Select the file you want to inspect at the bottom right.

Check the differences at the top.



